# InfoPath2010 Rules don't work, sometimes

Tags: workflow, infopath

I have a few basic rules on an InfoPath2010 form. I'm setting a flag value, sending data using main connection and close the form. It works fine for me and for generally all people in my company. Hovewer, sometimes is doesn't work. Such as a few minutes ago someone added an e-mail as attachment but form did not close and workflow did not trigger. Another one did the same thing and it worked for her fine. What can I do? What is the problem? I don't know how to solve it. Does attachment format affect the rules? I guess *.msg* document formats affects rules badly. Does anybody know anything about this?

Edit: I solved my problem. It was because of extra "." on attachment name. Now I know that *MyMail..msg* doesnt work but *MyMail.msg* works. The problem is ".." but why? Does SharePoint check attachment name and extension? How can I stop this?

Comment: But Mozilla Firefox still opens it correctly?

Comment: Yes. I only can't post form to the server. Also, "&" character is problem too. "A and B.docx" can posted with no erros but "A & B.docx" can not be posted :s

Answer (score 1):

I believe any question should have an answer but not discussion and disputes. At least, in SE sites it is so...

If the problems happen in Internet Explorer but not in Mozilla Firefox (what I observed myself, as well as vice versa) then the answer to question:

- "Does SharePoint check attachment name and extension?" is "No". The problem is in browser used.
- and to question "What can I do?" is probably to use workarounds requiring less time and work